# Boolean testing vs exception in stringstream

Tags: c++, performance, error-handling, c++20, stringstream

I want to short-circuit when an I/O operation on a `std::istringstream`/`std::ostringstream` fails, to avoid unnecessarily calling the rest of any chained `<<`/`>>` operators on the already **failed** *(x)stringstream* object. Some of my overloaded `<<`/`>>` operators do a bit of non-trivial formatting/parsing, so calling them on a failed stream object will waste their CPU cycles.

The resulting `ostringstream` (`oss` in the below code) is then inserted into a `std::ofstream` in one piece. I've used `std::cout` instead for demonstration.

Two approaches come to my mind. Below is a very minimal example.

1. testing with the ***bool operator***:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


int main()
{
    constexpr auto delimiter { ';' };

    std::ostringstream oss;

    const bool success = oss << "Hi" &&
                         oss << delimiter &&
                         oss << 8.02 &&
                         oss << delimiter &&
                         oss << false &&
                         oss << delimiter &&
                         oss << std::bitset<10> { 0b01010 } &&
                         oss << delimiter &&
                         oss << '\n';

    if ( success ) std::cout << oss.view(); // Hi;8.02;0;0000001010;
    else return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

2. throwing an ***exception***:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr auto delimiter { ';' };

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss.exceptions( std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit );

    try
    {
        oss << "Hi"
            << delimiter
            << 8.02
            << delimiter
            << false
            << delimiter
            << std::bitset<10> { 0b01010 }
            << delimiter
            << '\n';
    }
    catch ( const std::ios_base::failure& e )
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << oss.view(); // Hi;8.02;0;0000001010;
}
```

Obviously, the compiler generates different code for the two approaches (with the exception-based approach having noticeably less code), though I'm not sure which one can be faster in the above use case.

Which one might be a better solution? I must insert/extract ~20 values to/from the stream objects. It could be a gain in efficiency if the right choice were made.

Comment: I don't think you can rely that operands will not be evaluated in approach 2. But the bigger problem is that you *think* you could gain efficiency. Don't guess. If and only if your program doesn't meet performance requirements, use profiler to find choking points and solve those. Otherwise you can spend months doing microoptimisations to irrelevant parts of your program without any gain. If you run profiler and find that this really is a problem in your code, try both versions and see if they improve performance, or run a benchmark to select better one.

Comment: "It could be a gain in efficiency if the right choice were made".    You ever heard of premature optimisation?   Optimising for efficiency without doing measurements/profiling to assess a need/benefit is premature.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen True. However, even a slight bit of insight would still act like guidance here. I will eventually test both once the whole program is complete.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen "*I don't think you can rely that operands will not be evaluated in approach 2*" How? Isn't an exception thrown immediately when one of the calls to `operator<<` throws?

Comment: At first I was going to recommend against using exceptions because of their cost but in order to make the bool case short circuit you would have to check after each stream operation and if has failed then skip the rest of the input statements somehow.  The order of stream operations is sequenced so if the first operation fails then the exception would be thrown and the rest of the processing would be skipped.  I say code both and then profile for all cases.  See if one approach is better overall with that info.

Comment: Throwing exceptions is almost never a speed optimization. Besides, every [formatted output function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedOutputFunction) (`operator<<`) begins by constructing a [`sentry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/sentry) object and returns immediately if that object indicates that the stream is in a failed state. Just do the insertions and don't check the stream state until the last one has been done.

Comment: @PeteBecker Is this also true for overloaded operators? Or do I have to construct and check a `sentry` object in my implementation?

Comment: @digito_evo if you implement your own stream operators then you have to construct and check the stream `sentry` yourself

Comment: @digito_evo — if your overloaded stream inserter uses the builtin ones internally you don’t need to check the stream state for things to work correctly. But a time-consuming inserter (for example, one that loops through a container) should probably check the stream state on entry. It doesn’t necessarily need a `sentry` object; it can check the status bits directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question "what is faster" is unanswerable, I'll try to explain what happens in each case. Still, I'd like to underline strongly that this answer should be taken as academic consideration and you should not introduce changes in code based only on what you read here. Profile your code, find chokepoints, fix them and when in doubt about possible fixes, benchmark them (or implement both and profile again). Don't ever optimise based on a hunch that something may be slow.

The question that you have to answer is "what am I trying to prevent?". If you are trying to prevent calling the body of built-in `operator<<` when stream is in failed state, that's already done for you, as Pete noted in comments. That means, nothing will try to convert numeric value to string representation nor any string will be copied into the stream nor any operation on output or files will happen. If you do overload `operator<<` for your own types and these overloads do significant work *before* handing results to built-in operator, that work will still happen).
Example:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyType1& t) {
    return os << t.a << ' ' << t.b << ", " << t.c; // almost nothing is done if !os
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MyType2& t) {
    return os << t.toString(); // `toString` has to be evaluated fully before os is checked for fail
}
```

If you however want to prevent evaluation of operand to `operator<<` (e.g., construction of temporary object), that's much more problematic. Your first approach does prevent construction of any object like that `std::bitset<10>` after `oss` goes into failed state. This comes at a price of adding multiple jumps into assembly, and jumps aren't good for performance either. Your second approach is only guaranteed to do same in C++17 and higher, due to new [order of evaluation rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) that add sequencing to `operator <<`. Before C++17, it's unspecified whether all the remaining objects are created or not.

So, to sum up:

1. Approach 1 does prevent evaluation of operands once the stream failed, so it does prevent extra object constructions or calling `toString()` in above example. The price is adding more branches in assembly code, which generally isn't the best for performance (compiler may or may not optimise to assume it's unlikely for stream to fail).
2. Since C++17, approach 2 does prevent evaluation of operands one after the stream has failed. One operand right after fail will still be evaluated, since it only throws when next read happens on a failed stream. The price is adding exceptions to code, which are usually very expensive.
3. Before C++17, approach 2 gives no guarantees about evaluation of arguments. Compiler may choose to evaluate all operands before ever doing anything with `oss` if it decides it would be faster.

To show it on example, let's assume this output failed somehow:

```
    const bool success = oss << "Hi" &&
                         oss << delimiter && // this one failed
                         oss << std::bitset<10> { 0b01010 } &&
                         oss << delimiter &&
                         oss << std::string(13, 'n');
                         oss << '\n';
```

Approach 1 will not create `std::bitset` or `str::string` object, approach 2 will create `std::bitset` and throw immediately after in C++17 (avoiding creation of `std::string`), before C++17 approach 2 depends on the compiler - `std::bitset` will be created, `std::string` may or may not be.

Comment: It'd be good if you were clearer about what "approach 1" is, and "approach 2". I consider myself a C++ expert, and I *think* you have the key information here, but it's really hard to understand and be sure.

Comment: It would be good if you clearly mentioned that one option is to simply add `if (!os) return os;` in the `operator<<` overloads, wherever you want them to fast-fail, to avoid things like `return os << t.toString();` wasting cycles for a already-failed stream.

Comment: This is almost what I needed to know. The only thing missing here that caught my eye is the sentry object mentioned earlier. Maybe I should check the source of my target std library implementation to see how it utilizes the sentry object inside the operator to fast-fail.

Comment: @digito_evo you can read about the [`ostream::sentry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/sentry) and [`istream::sentry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/sentry) on cppreference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I took a look at the provided examples for both. Do you think just constructing and checking the sentry object and then doing the actual I/O is enough? Just like the examples do.

Comment: @digito_evo that is exactly how it works. Don't do any work at all in an overloaded operator until you first validate that the stream is not already in an error state to begin with. If the stream is ok, then a subsequent I/O fails, the stream is put into an error state for subsequent checks to see, and a `failure` exception is thrown if `exceptions()` is enabled on the stream.

Comment: Nice answer. Got my vote! _Side note:_ [Refining Expression Evaluation Order for Idiomatic C++](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf) by Gabriel Dos Reis, Herb Sutter, and Jonathan Caves – This paper describes the changes that were adopted in C++17.

Answer (score 1):

Generally: don't use exceptions with streams. It's slower, and almost never the best answer.

If your goal is for an `operator<<` overload to fast-fail, and thus not waste cpu cycles, then just check for that. All the built-in ones already do this, so you only have to check it for your own complex work.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& oss, const myThing& r) {
    oss << "Hi" << delimiter << 8.02 << delimiter << false << delimiter;
    if (!oss) return oss; // if failure, quit before std::bitset<10>
    return oss << std::bitset<10> { 0b01010 } << delimiter << '\n';
}
```

That's it. Super easy.